# Something wrong while installing Bochs

Tags: bochs

After I type:  ./configure --enable-debugger --enable-disasm

something goes wrong:

checking for ALL optimizations enabled... no
ERROR: handlers-chaining speedups are not supported with internal debugger yet

I wonder how to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit config.h and change 1 to 0 in
    #define BX_SUPPORT_HANDLERS_CHAINING_SPEEDUPS 1